# How extract JPEG image from H264 stream in constant time

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, h.264

I want to extract a JPEG frame from a H264 stream on disk. The extraction needs to be as fast as possible for my real-time requirements.

Until now I have been using `ffmpeg-python` lib which is just a python wrapper for `ffmpeg`. Here is a code snippet:

```
out, _ = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('./5sec.h264')
    .filter('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(144))
    .output('pipe:', vframes=1, format='image2', vcodec='h264')
    .run(capture_stdout=True)
)
```

This outputs the jpeg to stdout, with some effort I could read this into my program.

However, as I use larger and larger stream files the extraction time to grab the JPEG increases. I thought lookup time would be constant as `ffmpeg` is highly optimised?

Is there a constant time solution to lookup and return a frame from a h264 (or even mjpeg) format stream on disk?

Edit:
Heres the command I use without the python wrapper:
`ffmpeg -i 5sec.h264 -frames:v 1 -filter:v "select=gte(n\,25)" -f image2 frame.jpg`

here's output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, h264, from '5sec.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1a25390] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'frame.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.4 q=6.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.467x    
video:63kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Note, achieved FPS is 0.4. When I increase the requested frame to be the 125th frame rather than the 25th, the FPS goes down to 0.1.

Comment: Forget the wrapper for now until you get plain ffmpeg working first. Show the actual ffmpeg command being executed, and copy and paste all of the text from the ffmpeg log.

Comment: ok, these are now included.

Comment: I don't think you can get constant time when the input video is raw h264 stream. That is because raw h264 stream is **non-seekable** (for example: you can't seek to the third second and start extracting frames from there, using `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -i 5sec.h264`... ). So FFmpeg reads all the frames from the beginning of the file up to the desired frame. Using a container like `5sec.mp4` my solve it. But fast seeking is only to a **key frame**, so you it depends on the "GOP size" of the input.

Comment: I converted 5sec to .mp4 with this command: `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i 5sec.h264 -c copy 5sec.mp4`

Using my original ffmpeg command on the mp4 file yields the same seeking time to frame 125:
`ffmpeg -i 5sec.mp4 -frames:v 1 -filter:v "select=gte(n\,25)" -f image2 frame2.jpg`. It's still slow!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the H.264 stream has a container file, you may seek to the position of the frame, instead of reading all frames from the beginning of the file.

Instead of using `select` filter, use `-ss` argument (argument of `input` method).

The FFmpeg command line resembles the following:

```
ffmpeg -ss 14.4 -i in.mp4 -vframes 1 frame.jpg
```

---

Why do we need a container (like MP4)?

The MP4 container file uses an "index" with the position of every key frame in the video file.
When we need to seek to a specific time in the file, we can skip to the closest key frame before the "time", and decode few remaining frames.

The raw h264 stream, without a container has no index, so we can't do the seeking.

---

Start by creating a sample MP4 file (for making the code sample reproducible).

The following code sample builds a synthetic video file at 10Hz, with an advanced frame counter:

```
import ffmpeg

in_file_name = 'in.mp4'
fps = 10

# Build synthetic video, for testing - 1500 frames with advanced counder:
# Use g=50, for forcing a key frame every 50 frames (for testing).
(
    ffmpeg
    .input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1500', f='lavfi', r=fps)
    .filter('setpts', 'N/{}/TB'.format(fps))
    .output(in_file_name, vcodec='libx264', g=50, crf=17, pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel='panic')
    .global_args('-hide_banner')
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
```

---

Measuring time using `select` filter, and using **seeking**:

The example extracts frame `1440` instead of `144`, for better showing the time differences.

```
import ffmpeg
import time

in_file_name = 'in.mp4'

fps = 10

extracted_frame = 1440

# Build synthetic video, for testing - 1500 frames with advanced counder:
# Use g=50, for forcing a key frame every 50 frames (for testing).
#(
#    ffmpeg
#    .input('testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1500', f='lavfi', r=fps)
#    .filter('setpts', 'N/{}/TB'.format(fps))
#    .output(in_file_name, vcodec='libx264', g=50, crf=17, pix_fmt='yuv420p', loglevel='panic')
#    .global_args('-hide_banner')
#    .overwrite_output()
#    .run()
#)

start = time.time()
for i in range(10):  # Measure 10 iterations.
    # Extract the extracted_frame'th frame into frame.jpg
    (
        ffmpeg
        .input(in_file_name)
        .filter('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(extracted_frame))
        .output('frame.jpg', vframes=1, loglevel='panic')
        .global_args('-hide_banner')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run()
    )
end = time.time()
print('Time using select filter: {}'.format(end - start))


start = time.time()
for i in range(10):  # Measure 10 iterations.
    # Extract the extracted_frame'th frame into frame.jpg
    (
        ffmpeg
        .input(in_file_name, ss='{}'.format(extracted_frame / fps))
        .output('frame.jpg', vframes=1, loglevel='panic')
        .global_args('-hide_banner')
        .overwrite_output()
        .run()
    )
end = time.time()
print('Time using seeking: {}'.format(end - start))
```

---

Result:
`Time using select filter: 1.1203510761260986`
`Time using seeking: 0.36171388626098633`

---

In both cases `frame.jpg` shows `1440`:
[image]